# How to fix import error when running a juptyer notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a `python jupyter` notebook which I am trying to execute on the command line. Here is the command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=60 --output out_file test.ipynb
```

And here is a test version of this notebook (`test.ipynb`)

```
{"cells":[{"metadata":{"deletable":true,"editable":true},"cell_type":"markdown","source":["# Morphology analysis with neurom\n","\n","You can find the full documentation of neurom on http://neurom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html ."]},{"metadata":{"collapsed":false,"deletable":true,"editable":true,"trusted":false},"cell_type":"code","source":["%matplotlib inline\n","from copy import deepcopy\n","\n","from IPython.display import display, HTML\n","import urllib, zipfile, os\n","\n","try:\n","    import neurom\n","    from neurom import viewer, stats\n","except ImportError:\n","    !pip2 install neurom\n","    import neurom\n","    from neurom import viewer, stats"],"execution_count":null,"outputs":[]}],"metadata":{"kernelspec":{"name":"python2","display_name":"Python 2","language":"python"},"language_info":{"version":"2.7.6","mimetype":"text/x-python","file_extension":".py","codemirror_mode":{"version":2,"name":"ipython"},"nbconvert_exporter":"python","name":"python","pygments_lexer":"ipython2"}},"nbformat":4,"nbformat_minor":2}
```

which corresponds to the following code:

```
get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
from copy import deepcopy

from IPython.display import display, HTML
import urllib, zipfile, os

try:
    import neurom
    from neurom import viewer, stats
except ImportError:
    get_ipython().system(u'pip2 install neurom')
    import neurom
    from neurom import viewer, stats
```

Running this code with the command above, I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named neurom
```

although this module is installed in the current setting. So why is python not picking up this module?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the execution of the notebook does not use the current environment (like a `virtualenv` for example), and you have to 'add' it to the `jupyter` notebook.

So first you generate a standard config by using this command

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

generating usually a file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. In that file you have to add the following part

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines=[
    'import sys; sys.path.append("path-to-add")'
]
```

to add path(s) to your execution.

See also thread [here](https://gist.github.com/yasushisakai/86da64df10581d37af709387f45f9312).